# Illegal instruction when computing big matrix with numpy.cov

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Everything is in the title. I'm trying to compute a covariance matrix with numpy.cov. I've got N samples of 50 observables. I'm simply doing this (as a test):

```
input_data=np.ones((50,N))
cov_matrix = numpy.cov(input_data)
```

When N is small ( < 15), I have no problem, I obtain a coherent result, but as soon as N get higher, I obtain an Illegal Instruction.

I wonder if there is a limitation of the numpy.cov function, but I didn't find anything ... Does someone already have a similar problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Illegal instruction results from running code that was compiled for a CPU with an instruction extension that the CPU, you are running it on doesn't have.

Comment: Try compiling from source.

Comment: I now run my code on another CPU, and it works. this was the easiest solution for me because I can't install/compile on the cluster I'm using. Thanks for the answers !